# Plotting format 1d 10:05 in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How i able to plot this in gnuplot the following times in gnuplot?

But the graph does not seem to adapt the hours after the days.

```
set timefmt "%jd %H:%M"
```

in my test.csv there is:

```
0,1d 10:15
1,1d 10:05
2,1d 1:50
3,2d 3:30
```

plot "test.csv"
[image]

As seen in the picture the time is not plotted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell gnuplot that your data separator is comma. Per default it is whitespace.
In the example below skip the `$Data` datablock and in the plot command replace `$Data` by `Test.csv`.
There, column2 is plotted versus column1. Maybe you want it the other way round, it's not clear from your question, graph and plot command.

**Code:**

```
### plotting time data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0,1d 10:15
1,1d 10:05
2,1d 1:50
3,2d 3:30
EOD

set datafile separator comma
myTimeFmt = "%jd %H:%M"
set format y myTimeFmt time

plot $Data u 1:(timecolumn(2,myTimeFmt)) w lp pt 7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]